# Access Graph API from Web API throws unauthorized error v2.0

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I have a client app that makes requests to a web API. I need to make a request from the web api to the graph api to get the upn claim of the logged in user. I am getting an access token successfully but when I try to request the graph API it throws an Unauthorized error. Here is the code:

```
ConfidentialClientApplication cl = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
    clientId,
    "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/token",
    "https://localhost:44321/",
    new ClientCredential(appKey),
    new TokenCache(), null);

AuthenticationResult authResult = await cl.AcquireTokenForClientAsync(new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" });

string oid = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;

client = new HttpClient();
request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/" + oid);
request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);

response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

I can't figure out what I am missing here. Would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the 'Common' end point for Client Credentials flow you can try to using the tenant specific endpoint to get the access token .e.g.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

Also, you can check the application permissions scope on the access token you have received. You can use an JWT token decoder tool like [jwt.io](http://jwt.io) to validate the claims on the token